# The same phrase is repeating while using different command

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm developing a telegram bot. I do this on my code and the question is, why my bot repeat the same first phrase when I put the second command?

```
TOKEN_BOT = "secret token"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN_BOT)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["hello", "start"])
def send(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Welcome, I am RIOPy! BOT designed to organize your SME to your liking. To start write / start and we will get to work.")

bot.polling()

def enviar_start (message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Great! wait 5 seconds.")

#HERE DATABASE CODE

time.sleep(5)
bot.reply_to, "DATABASE CREATED"

bot.polling()
```

PS: The code is working now. I deleted bot.pulling() under the if, and i put the /hello and /start commands in 2 differents lines.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["hello"])
def send(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Welcome, I am RIOPy! BOT designed to organize your SME to your liking. To start write / start and we will get to work.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def enviar_start (message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Great! wait 5 seconds.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing your bot says when you send the /start command is also the first thing it says when you send the /hello command, because your bot's message handler for the /hello command is also the message handler for the /start command. To fix this, you need to create two separate message handlers, one for the /hello command and one for the /start command.

Comment: Thank you, you where right, i changed the code and i delete the bot.pulling() it was under the if.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following lines of code are not needed, you can delete them

````py
if message == "start":
    enviar_start(message)```

The edited code should work.
````

Comment: You where right! Thank you so much!